# Cannot be resolved to a variable, after asking user to input variable

Tags: java

It's probably something obvious, but when I'm trying to force the user to keep entering a value until he enters a valid value, I get an error that the variable cannot be resolved.

Then if I declare it beforehand I get an error saying duplicate value.

```
do {
    float x = Float.parseFloat(javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 1");
} while (x != 1);
```

Isn't the compiler supposed to execute the `do` statement first, before worrying about the `while`?

Comment: The compiler does not execute anything. It compiles the Java code to bytecode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

declare `x` before the loop, make its scope more broder like below :

```
float x = 0.0f;
do {
    x = Float.parseFloat(javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 1"); 
} while (x != 1);
```

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, add the missing closing bracket please. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is something rather obvious.

You're declaring the variable inside a block, which means it will cease to exist as soon as you hit the end of the block. The end of the block is with the }

Try:

```
float x;
do {
    Float.parseFloat(javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 1"));
} while(x != 1);
```

Or alternatively:

```
float x = 0;
while(x != 1) {
    Float.parseFloat(javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 1"));
}
```

Please also mind the missing closing bracket in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 float x=0.0f;
     do{
        x = Float.parseFloat(javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 1"));
         }
         while (x != 1);
```

Cause for the error is , you have declared the `x` inside the `loop` its not visible in while condition variable `x`  and `closing parenthesis` have been missed at the end of `initialization`.

Correct me if 'm wrong